# C# : Int to Hex Byte conversion to write into an Hex File

Tags: c#, integer, hex, byte

I'm having problems in converting an integer into a byte array in hex format to write into my Hex File.
I have read and tried several solutions that I went over in here and in many other sites.

I read the integer from the textbox and convert it into an int like that:

```
int value= int.Parse(textEditValue.EditValue.ToString());
```

An example input of this number is like:

```
int value= 568
```

And I need to write into the hex file like that:

```
38 36 35 //reversed version of 568 because of endiannes
```

What I have tried is:

```
byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
Array.Reverse(intBytes); // Because the hex-file is little-endian
byte[] resultBytes = intBytes;
```

When the above code runs it writes into the hex file like :

```
38 02 00 00
```

How I wrote into the file:

```
    for(int i = 0x289C; i >= 0x289C - resultBytes.Length; i--)
   {
        binaryWriter.BaseStream.Position = i;
        binaryWriter.Write(resultBytes[count]);
        count++;
    }
```

I appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: The need to write ASCII string representations of hexadecimal values to a file seems really strange. How is this to be used - is it some kind of exercise?

Comment: For a project with specific requirements. @500 - Internal Server Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct for converting an integer to hex.

The hex representation of `568` is `00 00 02 38` - so reversed for little Endian, you end up with what you got.

To get your desired output you need to view it, not as integer, but as an ASCII string. If you need to make sure the text input can be converted to an integer, you can do something like this:

```
if (int.TryParse(textEditValue.EditValue.ToString(), out int myInt)){
    byte[] intBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textEditValue.EditValue.ToString());
    Array.Reverse(intBytes); // Because the hex-file is little-endian
    byte[] resultBytes = intBytes;
}
else {
    //Not a valid integer
}
```